# Construct all possible 3-letter words from A,B. Repetition of letters is allowed

Tags: combinatorics

I have two letters A and B. I need to construct all possible 3-letter words. Repetition of letters is allowed. I know that the answer to this problem is `2^3=8`. But how can I construct the words in Mathematica?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
StringJoin @@@ Tuples[{"A", "B"}, 3]
```

> ```
> {"AAA", "AAB", "ABA", "ABB", "BAA", "BAB", "BBA", "BBB"}
> ```